# PHP assertive array to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

So my website has received some data in the form of a `PHP` associative array (see below) and I'm trying to convert it to something I can interact with using JavaScript.

[image]

JavaScript seems to treat it as just a string and I've had problems using `JSON.parse`. I have control over the format of this data before it arrives at my JS do I need to restructure it??

Extra Info: Web page A requests data from web page B then web page B collects the data from a database and returns a big array. The array above is the response from web page B in web page A. Each index (`["tag"],["current_ids"]` etc) actually have large array contained in them, I just shortened it to 1 for ease of understanding.

Comment: You should encode the array to JSON in PHP!

Comment: You should also show your code ... if you want any hope of having any practical help. People are guessing that you are not using `json_encode`, but frankly it is just a WAG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data on the web is always sent and received as strings. JavaScript needs the data in a format that it can understand, for example `JSON`.

PHP has an in-built function to convert your data, e.g. your array, into JSON called `json_encode()`. It also has a sister function for decoding JSON into PHP called `json_decode()`.

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Depending on your setup, you'll want JavaScript to make a XHR request to an endpoint  where you're running PHP and then you'll use PHP to process that request and return a JSON string.

Alternatively, you could use PHP to directly echo the JSON string into JavaScript, for example:

`<script>
<?php echo "var myData = ${json};"; ?>
</script>`

XHR is the better practice in general but you should use whichever approach best suits your needs.